# Notepad++. Как вставить одинаковый текст в пустые строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Например вставить WWW

Было:

пустая строка

строка 2

пустая строка

строка 4

пустая строка

строка 6

Стало:

WWW

строка 2

WWW

строка 4

WWW

строка 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск-змена
Регулярные выражения

```
Найти :^$
Заменить:WWW
```

---

```
строка 2

строка 4

строка 6
```

---

```
WWW
строка 2
WWW
строка 4
WWW
строка 6
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Oopss !